# How to create a single one page navigation?

Tags: jquery, css

For a while, I am trying to code a nice working one page navigation, that scroll to the right anchor section and update his current state in the menu.

So which kind of function do I need?
- A function that handles the click event: when the user clicks on an anchor link it should scroll to that section and update the current state of the menu.

- A function that get rid of the active state, while scrolling.

Beside that, I used a fixed header. So the height of the header should be minus the scroll position to avoid overlapping content by the sticky header.

Came up with this:

```
// An offset to push the content down from the top
    var offset = $('#header').outerHeight();




    $('#primary-navwrapper').find('li a[href^="#"]').click(function(event) { 

        // Current class switch
        $(this).removeClass("current");
        $(this).addClass("current");


        // The id of the section we want to go to.
        var anchorId = $(this).attr("href");


        // Our scroll target : the top position of 
        // the section that has the id referenced by our href.
        var target = $(anchorId).offset().top - offset;         
        //console.log(target);


        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: target }, 500, function () {
            window.location.hash = anchorId;        
        });


        // Prevent from default action to intitiate
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;

    });

function setActiveListElements(event) {

        // Get the offset of the window from the top of page
        var windowPos = $(window).scrollTop();

        $('nav li a[href^="#"]').each(function() { 
            var currentId = $(this);
            console.log(this);

            // if for active
            var target = currentId.attr("href");
            console.log(target);

            var offsetTop = target.position().top - offset;
            //var offsetBottom = offsetTop + target.height();

            if (target.length > 0) {
                console.log(target.position().top + target.height());
                if (target.position().top - offset <= windowPos && target.position().top + target.height() > windowPos) {
                    $('#primary-navwrapper li a').removeClass("current");
                    $(this).addClass("current");
                }
            }

        });

    }
```

It will scroll to its position, but the current state will not be updated. Beside that, I tried also to update the hash in the URL on scroll, but doesn't know how I should get this done.

Also I doesn't no if this can be more shorter and better coded, so advice is welcome :)

Comment: you can use (I tried to ... but I got error in ....) instead of (I want ...) .. after that I think you will get a help .. your question's answer is simple .. but it just  need time .. Good Luck

Comment: Have you consider using [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) ?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this jQuery plugin called SMINT. I think this is what you are after.

http://www.outyear.co.uk/smint/

If this is the solution don't forget to mark this answer as the right answer by clicking the Tick. If you wish to use your current code then I can help you (Just comment bellow and I will assist you) but I really think this plugin is an easier route but I don't know if this is the effect you are after.